MSBuild SDK cannot find Microsoft.Common.props
I am attempting to parse a solution and its projects using MSBuild SDK. The function below is able to successfully open the solution file and list containing projects.
I am using the latest version of VS 2022 targeting .NET 8 in a Console app. MSBuild NuGet package reference is: Microsoft.Build 17.10.4.
public static void GenerateCodeMsBuild ()
{
    var pathSolution = $@"D:\...\DomainBuilder.sln";
    var solution = Microsoft.Build.Construction.SolutionFile.Parse(pathSolution);

    Console.WriteLine($@"Solution: {solution}.");

    foreach (var project in solution.ProjectsInOrder)
        Console.WriteLine($@" - {project.ProjectName}.");
}

In order to gain access to further project elements such as references, folders, files, etc., I tried the Evaluation namespace as follows:
public static void GenerateCodeMsBuild ()
{
    var pathProject = $@"D:\...\DomainBuilder.ConsoleApp.csproj";
    var projectOptions = new Microsoft.Build.Definition.ProjectOptions();

    var project = Microsoft.Build.Evaluation.Project.FromFile(pathProject, projectOptions);
    var projectInstance = Microsoft.Build.Execution.ProjectInstance.FromFile(pathProject, projectOptions);
}

Both above called to FromFile result in the following exception:
InvalidProjectFileException (-2146233088): [The imported project "D:\...\DomainBuilder.ConsoleApp\bin\Debug\net8.0-windows10.0.22621.0\Current\Microsoft.Common.props" was not found. Confirm that the expression in the Import declaration "D:\...\DomainBuilder.ConsoleApp\bin\Debug\net8.0-windows10.0.22621.0\Current\Microsoft.Common.props" is correct, and that the file exists on disk.  C:\Program Files\dotnet\sdk\8.0.303\Sdks\Microsoft.NET.Sdk\Sdk\Sdk.props].
I can verify that the project file is valid and is a newly created project from within VS.
I am guessing this has something to do the empty instance of ProjectOptions and am not sure how to generate, obtain, or reference the Microsoft.Common.props file. This file is not created when I create and build a new .NET 8 project from scratch.
Any advise would be appreciated.

I did find C:\Program Files\dotnet\sdk\8.0.303\Current\Microsoft.Common.props and copied it into the folder indicated by the exception. The error has now changed to: InvalidProjectFileException (-2146233088): [The SDK 'Microsoft.NET.SDK.WorkloadAutoImportPropsLocator' specified could not be found.  C:\Program Files\dotnet\sdk\8.0.303\Sdks\Microsoft.NET.Sdk\targets\Microsoft.NET.Sdk.ImportWorkloads.props].

Why are you parsing solution files and project files? What are you trying to achieve? Is the parsing issue an XY problem?
